# how to override bootstrap btn-info hover css

Tags: css

I am attempting to change the default colors of btn-info using a custom css file.

I am using

```
.btn-info {
background-color:rgb(111,192,89);
color:white;
}
```

This works perfectly but when I try to change the hover i always seem to get the default bootstrap

```
.btn-info:hover {
background-color:yellow !important;
color:black !important;

}
```

Suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Regards

M.R.

Comment: Your current css seems to be working fine for me as can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/dwgt3qv9/2/. Are you loading your custom css after your bootstrap css??

Comment: Make sure to use the same selector bootstrap is using with :hover

Comment: @am777 - "same selector"???

Comment: @andrewl63... if the .btn-info works then im pretty sure the custom css is being loaded after bootstrap...